# Printing graph (vertex, edge) in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph-theory

What is the easiest way to print a graph in Python? i.e. I am wanting to visualize the maximum clique of a graph.

My current data structures are:

```
adjacency_matrix = [[False, True, False, ...], 
                    [True, False, True, ...],
                    ..]

adjacency_set = [[45, 2], [1, 32], ...]

max_clique = [23, 143, 1, 2, 42, 12, 3, ...] # the vertices in the max clique
```

Would I use matplotlib to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Consider using [networkx](https://networkx.github.io) package for creating and manipulating graphs. It also has visualization functions such as drawing with matplotlib.

Note that you will need to convert your data structure to one that can initialize networkx graph. [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/convert.html) is the docs.

Also you might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9217887/7044023) answer on how to visualize maximal cliques.

example:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.matrix([[1,1],[2,1]])
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19840595)

Comment: @PauloMattos Is this better?

Comment: yep! Thanks for the taking the time to improve your answer ;)

Comment: AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_numpy_matrix'

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain You ware correct the API has changed https://stackoverflow.com/a/75284568/7044023