# AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_numpy_matrix'

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

A is co occurrence dataframe. Why it shown AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_numpy_matrix'

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib
A=np.matrix(coocc)
G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was updated to `nx.from_numpy_array(A)`

Answer (score 14):

In networkx 3.0 the changelog shows the following "Remove `to_numpy_matrix` & `from_numpy_matrix` (#5746)"
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/release/release_3.0.html

You have to downgrade networkx or use `G=nx.from_numpy_array(A)` instead.
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/matrix_market.html

Comment: For those who may be interested, we can also utilize the [to_numpy_array](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_numpy_array.html) function.

It's useful to get the adjacency matrix from causalnex: `adj_matrix = nx.to_numpy_array(sm)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `G = nx.DiGraph(np.array(A))` instead of `G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(np.array(A), create_using=nx.Graph)`